# How to mock a object which created using new method

Tags: java, mockito, testng

We are using Mockito to mock objects. How do I mock an object that is created in service code? Below is the service code and test code. Any help?  Also I don't want to use Powermock now.

```
public class EventPublisher  {
    public void publishEvent(final String eventJson) {

        try {
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = getObjectMapper(true);
            Test testJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(event);
            testJson.getName();
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {

            return;
        }
        //publish();  some external call
    }
    private ObjectMapper getObjectMapper(boolean enableRootElement) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, enableRootElement);
        return objectMapper;
    }
}
```

test code:

```
   public void testPublishEvent() throws Exception {
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = mock(ObjectMapper.class);
                when(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(json))
.thenThrow(mock(JsonProcessingException.class));  //this is not getting invoked


}
```

Comment: If not going to use Powermock, then only workable solution left is refactoring that code to allow the tightly coupled dependency to be explicitly injected into the dependent class.

Comment: It's easy if you inject the dependency into the object.  You can then feel free to use either the production or the mock object.

Comment: Tbh, in the last 5 years I've been testing, I've only *had* to use Mockito for either legacy code or code domain-specific code that required strange relationships (people attempting to creating "DSLs" in Java). Natural testing is possible as long as you write testable code. As duffymo has suggested, your code is not testable. I recommend looking into how to write testable code, reduce your dependency on external libraries that support testing - reduce the need for such support. Not to say Mockito doesn't simplify it (readability), but being *required* to use these libs is another story.

Comment: @VinceEmigh Did you mean Powermock? A mocking library of some sort is absolutely necessary for testing external interactions, even with "testable code". If by "natural testing" you mean without simulating any external actors, well, sure, as long as you're doing 100% pure functions with no side effects, which aren't all that useful in business applications.

Comment: Something wrong with the code `objectMapper.writeValueAsString` returns `String`, not object of custom type, please fix.

Comment: I agree with @chrylis, Mockito is a completely normal tool for testing, not a code smell. PowerMock, on the other hand, is a sign that you have problems because some code is bad (in other words, a code smell).

Comment: @chrylis Yes, I meant PowerMock. I've been programming for the past 49 hours (26, + the 23 since then), and I've even used Mockito since then. Replace occurances of "Mockito" in that comment with "PowerMock". Also, for "natural testing", yes, i was referring to the API being tested, not external actors that the API depends on. Goes to show how important breaks are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your suggestions. Though code refactoring is good idea, since the method is used in multiple places. Instead of increasing the scope of testing found below solution to fix current issue.

```
public class EventPubliserTest {

@Mock
private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

private class MockEventPublisher extends EventPublisher {
    @Override
    protected ObjectMapper getObjectMapper(boolean flag) {
        return objectMapper;
    }

}

@Test
public void testPublishEvent() throws Exception {
    EventPublisher eventPublisher = new MockEventPublisher();
    when(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(json)).thenThrow(mock(JsonProcessingException.class)); 
    //create or mock some json string
    eventPublisher.publishEvent(json);

    }
}
```

Comment: I dont have any default consturctor in my class ( say EventPublisher ) Then how i can use this.